# What to write in journal cover letter when research was conducted several years ago

Tags: peer-review, journals, paper-submission, editors

I am in the process of submitting a paper to a peer reviewed journal. The paper reports a study that was conducted 7 years ago. In the cover letter to editors that I have prepared, I point out that the topic remains timely, and I provide relevant references to illustrate this (which have also been used to update the paper). I feel that this information is sufficient at this time of initial submission, and that if the editors ask the reason for the delay in submitting the article, I can address it then. Any thoughts regarding this? Any suggestions for anything else to mention in the cover letter (aside from what normally goes in cover letters)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would mention that the study was done years back, at all.

Answer (score 2):

Delays in publishing results are normal for several reasons. Seven years might be a long time, but as long as your results are still relevant and writing a new publication on them has not become obsolete, it is irrelevant when they were generated. So do not mention it in the cover letter at all.